# Error on search result page

Tags: error, search, catalogsearch

Help! I can't figure out what's wrong with this one. Every time I type a correct search term in quick search, this one shows http://www.umdistributors.com/sc/catalogsearch/result/?q=product
Does anyone know how to solve this? thanks!

type "product" for the correct search term.

Answer (score 0):

Magento appends your URL with catalogsearch/result/?q={search term} when you search on something. The URL you've provided shows the correct URL for a search on the term "product" but produces 0 results.

You can configure how search works via System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search.

Use Search type of 'combine' to do a like and full text search. If your product has 'product' in the name it should now pick it up.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I tried what you gave but still shows the same result. :( do you have any solutions ?

Comment: Hi Ken since I last looked it appears you've changed something on the site as this page isn't working at all now. I think you need to rollback to your previous php version and get it up and running again so you can see results.